# How to automatically design a dynamic table when fetching row (PHP /MySQLi)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'd like to design a dynamic table when fetching row in php/mysql.
Please see attached image of the example.

See my code below, it works almost well but the vertical bar in the middle doesn't seems to fit well.

```
for ($i = 0;$i<$result->num_rows;$i++){
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

   //echo "* ".$row["0"]."<br>";   // Work great

   //echo "* " .$row["0"] .$row["1"] ."<br>";

   echo "| " .$row["1"] ."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" ." | " ."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" .$row["2"] ."<br>";
}
```

[image: image of my code result]

What I want to do:

[image: image of what I want to do]

Comment: why soo many &nbsp;??

Comment: this question makes no sense at all

Comment: cant you use tables?

Comment: use tables!!. You've got bootstrap table , datatable! What you are doing is not dynamic. It's just weird

Comment: How do I use "tables" or "datatable" don't know what is it? can you provide me even a example? so how do i use it from my above code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is an example of how to echo HTML [tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) from php code

```
echo "<table><thead></thead><tbody>"
for ($i = 0;$i<$result->num_rows;$i++){
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    echo "<tr>".
         "<td>{$row["0"]}</td>".
         "<td>{$row["1"]}</td>".
         "<td>{$row["2"]}</td>".
         "</tr>\n";
}
 echo "</tbody></table>"
```

CSS

```
td{
    padding: 3px; /*add space to all directions (top, right,bottom, left)*/
    padding-left: 6px; /*add space to the left side only*/
}
```

Put that css in the css files of the HTML document (it will be applied to all `td` elements in the document). Or ***-which is not recommended-*** by inline-css as like this

```
  echo "<tr>".
         "<td style='padding-left:6px'>{$row["0"]}</td>".
         "<td style='padding-left:6px'>{$row["1"]}</td>".
         "<td style='padding-left:6px'>{$row["2"]}</td>".
         "</tr>\n";
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your effort, Sir.  It's solved my problem. I appreciate that.  Indeed I used  (&nbsp) in order to create space like this `"<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{$row["2"]}</td>".`   Is there any other way of doing it professionally or is it only done like I did?  Thanks in advance !

Comment: @J.Doe You are welcome . styling = [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) . I will edit the answer to show you how to make that space with css

Comment: @J.Doe I strongly recommend that you take sometime with learning more about HTML before you start building it with php. Good luck to you!

Comment: and HTML too. Thanks